# get back and fore colors from excel cell to datagrid view c#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I want to read 1st line from Excel file and apply to DataGridView as column header. During that operation I got issue to read correctly foreground color and background colors.

**View side**

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count; ++i)
{
  this.dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Style = controller.getHeadingStyle(i);
  this.dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Value = controller.getHeadingValue(i);
}
```

**Controller side**

```
internal DataGridViewCellStyle getHeadingStyle(int i)
{
  var DGVCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
  var excelStyle = excel.getStyleAt(1, i + 1);
  DGVCellStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(Int32.Parse(excelStyle.Font.Color.ToString()));
  view.Log(i + " excelStyle.Font.Color: " + excelStyle.Font.Color);
  DGVCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(Int32.Parse(excelStyle.Interior.Color.ToString()));
  view.Log(i + " excelStyle.Interior.Color: " + excelStyle.Interior.Color);

  view.Log(i + " DGVCellStyle.ForeColor: " + DGVCellStyle.ForeColor);
  view.Log(i + " DGVCellStyle.BackColor: " + DGVCellStyle.BackColor);
  return DGVCellStyle;
}

internal string getHeadingValue(int i)
{
  return excel.getValueAt(1, i + 1);
}
```

**Excel Object side**

```
internal Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Style getStyleAt(int row, int col)
{
  return excelRange.Cells[row, col].Style;
}

public string getValueAt(int row, int col)
{
  var val = excelRange.Cells[row, col].Value;
  if (val == null)
  {
    val = "";
  }
  return val.ToString().Trim();
}
```

**Log output**

```
[09/08/2013 11:24:42]: 0 excelStyle.Font.Color: 0
[09/08/2013 11:24:42]: 0 excelStyle.Interior.Color: 16777215
[09/08/2013 11:24:42]: 0 DGVCellStyle.ForeColor: Color [Black]
[09/08/2013 11:24:42]: 0 DGVCellStyle.BackColor: Color [White]
[09/08/2013 11:24:42]: 1 excelStyle.Font.Color: 0
[09/08/2013 11:24:42]: 1 excelStyle.Interior.Color: 16777215
[09/08/2013 11:24:42]: 1 DGVCellStyle.ForeColor: Color [Black]
[09/08/2013 11:24:42]: 1 DGVCellStyle.BackColor: Color [White]
[09/08/2013 11:24:42]: 2 excelStyle.Font.Color: 0
[09/08/2013 11:24:42]: 2 excelStyle.Interior.Color: 16777215
[09/08/2013 11:24:42]: 2 DGVCellStyle.ForeColor: Color [Black]
[09/08/2013 11:24:42]: 2 DGVCellStyle.BackColor: Color [White]
[09/08/2013 11:24:42]: 3 excelStyle.Font.Color: 0
[09/08/2013 11:24:42]: 3 excelStyle.Interior.Color: 16777215
[09/08/2013 11:24:42]: 3 DGVCellStyle.ForeColor: Color [Black]
[09/08/2013 11:24:42]: 3 DGVCellStyle.BackColor: Color [White]
(etc)
```

**issue**

- looks all cell are black on white, that is not the case
- reading values at same time guaranty me I reading right Excel cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to get the color directly from the Cell range, not from the Style associated:

```
internal int getInteriorColorAt(int row, int col)
{
  return ((Excel.Range)excelRange.Cells[row, col]).Interior.Color;
}

internal int getFontColorAt(int row, int col)
{
  return ((Excel.Range)excelRange.Cells[row, col]).Font.Color;
}
```